# Calculate difference in days ActiveSupport:TimeWithZone in the most "rubyish" style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a feeling someone is going to point me to another question that answers this but I've been searching with no luck over this simple issue.

I have a Activerecord with a datetime property. It returns as an ActiveSupport:TimeWithZone. I know I can't compare that to DateTime.now because that doesn't include a zone so I need to use Time.zone. Makes sense.

What I'm wondering is stylewise is there a "cleaner" way to do this than subtracting and dividing the result by 86400?

Here's what I do:

```
((Time.zone.now - myActiveRecord.visit_date)/86400).to_i
```

Works but seems un-rubyish and I feel like I'm missing something. Should I be casting, comparing or converting some other route or is this really the typical way to do this in rails? Appreciate any tips or a link to a question that already covers this.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to output words when all is said and done?

Comment: I am limited to doing this in a model at the momemnt so I can't take advantage of time_ago_in_words helpers. I'm just taking the int value back to a client application. Thanks for the feedback everyone.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

One thing you can do to make it more readable is:

```
((Time.zone.now - myActiveRecord.visit_date) / 1.day).to_i
```

Edit:

Actually you can get rid of one set of the brackets with:

```
(Time.zone.now - myActiveRecord.visit_date).to_i / 1.day
```

Comment: There is actually a method for this that I mention below.

Comment: ``(Time.zone.now - 3.days.ago).to_i / 1.day`` will output ``2``

Comment: This does not always work. I had to do instead: `(myActiveRecord.end_date.to_datetime.to_i - Time.now.to_i)/1.day`

Comment: @dgilperez time passes as the two parts of the line evaluates. You need to set the time. `t = Time.zone.now` and then `(t - (t - 3.days)).to_i / 1.day`.

Comment: Watch out if you compare this value to something like `<= 7.days.to_i`. The switch to and from daylight savings time caught me more than once ;). And the code will only fail once a year :P.

Answer (score 20):

I know this question is a bit dated but I came across it while Googling for a similar problem. In my case I needed to know the difference in whole days on a macro and micro scale.

For example, I needed my code to be able to tell me that Dec 31, 2010 is 366 days before Jan 1, 2012 and that Dec 31, 2010 23:59 is 1 day away from Jan 1, 2011 00:00. The method above works in the former but in the case of the latter, it says they are 0 days apart.

What I ended up doing was using Ruby's `Date` class to do the math for me. Using the code above my method looks like this:

`(Time.zone.now.to_date - myActiveRecord.visit_date.to_date).to_i`

This will work with inputs in `Time` or `DateTime` due to the conversion. Another possible solution would be to first call `beginning_of_day` on each of the `Times` or `DateTimes` but in my case, the minutes were important.

Answer (score 4):

Rails actually has a method built in for just this sort of thing.

checkout [#time_ago_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words)

So, for the original case...

`((Time.zone.now - myActiveRecord.visit_date)/86400).to_i`

vs

`time_ago_in_words(myActiveRecord.visit_date)`

Comment: Actually that method returns a human readable string description, not the actual numeric difference.

Comment: The downvote is unnecessary. This is not the _best_ answer, but it is not a wrong answer either. In fact, in the context of this whole posting, this answer contains technique to be aware of.