# Rails: how to get the number of days when it was created to today's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate difference in days ActiveSupport:TimeWithZone in the most “rubyish” style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049941/calculate-difference-in-days-activesupporttimewithzone-in-the-most-rubyish-st)

I just needed to print out the number of days something was created_at to now.

I tried something like this but it keeps printing 0.

(Date.today - p.created_at).to_i

More example, when something was created_at(09-01-2012) the code should print the number 3 for x days ago from today's date(09-04-2012).

Comment: Note: `Date.today` is an instance of `Date`. `model.created_at` is an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` (similar to Ruby's Time class). `Time.now` is an instance of Time. Date.today isn't going to give you the resolution you want. `Time.now - p.created_at` will give you distance in seconds. The most naive solution would be to `(Time.now - p.created_at)/60/60/24`. :O)

Comment: Thanks danneu, how would I be able to convert to x days???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `distance_of_time_in_words` helper in the views. If you want something with better precision, I co-authored a gem called [dotiw](http://github.com/radar/dotiw) which provides the same helper method.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem like you. I use Jquery Timeago plugin from this site: [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

You can edit text and add your custom in your language.

For formating date I use this helper:

```
def date_show(d)
        date = Date.new(d)
        return date.in_time_zone.strftime("%d.%m.%Y @ [%H:%M]")
end
```

This is solution is cheaper than creating in background. If you can not use it in view, sorry for my answer.

Comment: This seems closer to what I need but does anyone know if there are methods where I can avoid using additional script?

Comment: It's very "expensive" doing it in background, but Ryan answer is without additional script, documentation for it: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words